# Words are not automatically breaking into two lines with "-"

Tags: overleaf, hyphenation, text, text-decorations

I am using this (LaTeX2e Proceedings Templates, http://www.icsoc.org/) but some words are not breaking down into two parts with "-" through out the paper. For example, see attached image.

[image]
**strong text**

Comment: Can you please show at least the preamble as code? Thanks // Try \hyphenation, see e.g. here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Hyphenation . I.e. tell your document how to treat these special terms.

Comment: These words are hyphenated properly by the default patterns, so something must be inhibiting them.  I see that these words are bold.  Are they set in a box, by any chance?

Comment: I used the \textbf{} or \textit{}. Nothing else. I dont know how to address. still problem